# angularjs orderBy not re-sorting after changes

Tags: angularjs, sorting

I have list a ul whose li's (using ng-repeat) are sorted using two filters, i.e. orderBy:['filter1', 'filter2']. This works just fine. Now, depending on what may happen in another list, this first list needs to re-sort itself. This also works fine, but if the change causing the re-sort is undone, the list does not re-sort itself. Can someone explain why this might be? As an example:

item1
item2
item3
(Expected behavior)

after change in another list:

item3
item1
item2
(Expected behavior)

After undoing change:

item3
item1
item2
(Wrong, should revert to first layout)

Comment: Can you reprocude this in a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: could be 20 different reasons...without some code it is anyone's guess

Comment: please create fiddle sir